# How to search records against a list of values without quote

Tags: sql, oracle

In an oracle table, I want to search all records with one of the attribute (Varchar) that matches any of the values in a very long list (>1000). I could use

```
select count(*) from report_tb where report_id in ('x001', 'x002', .....)
```

The thing is the list is saved in a excel spreadsheet and these values do not have quotes.

Another option would be create a temporary table and insert all the values to it and then use sub query:

```
select count(*) from report_tb where report_id in (select report_id from id_tmp)
```

However, I don't have permission to create table in the database. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Loading into a table is the way to go... Oracle max "in" length is 1000 items. Otherwise, if excel, just use `="'"&A1&"',"` and fire it off for the length of your list (replacing `A1` for the first cell in the list)

Comment: You could possibly use a collection, but you'd have to populate that in PL/SQL - or use multiple shorter collections with up to 1000 elements in each. If you can't create a temporary table, presumably you can't create an external table either?

Comment: I might suggest a variation on `like` but that would no doubt hit the maximum length limits of strings in Oracle.

Comment: Ask you DBA for permission to create tables - or ask your DBA to create the table for you.

Comment: You could also create the "temporary table" on the fly, in a subquery.

Comment: @mathguy how do I port everything from excel to that temporary table though?

Comment: It depends on what is available to you and how your Excel file communicates with Oracle, given the constraints (no privileges on the DB, for example). In Excel you can add single quotes around the strings, concatenate them and then pass this long string to Oracle - but it depends on how long it is. Some time ago I knew how to do all of this in a few lines of VBA (assuming you have privileges to do that - maybe you do, maybe you don't). If the string is too long, you can chop it into pieces and pass several strings from Excel to Oracle.